# How do I test unmarshalling

Tags: java, junit, apache-camel, cxf

We're using Camel to handle SOAP messages and direct them to different endpoints.

What is the easiest way of testing that unmarshalling is working properly?

**I need to get CXF to unmarshal my SOAP requests.**

Preferably I'd skip all the Camel mumbo jumbo and jack it directly into CXF somehow, but I can't seem to find any good was of doing that...

I have tried setting up [Camel tests](http://camel.apache.org/testing.html), but it only mocks the endpoints without actually unmarshalling the message.

Comment: Well, you're testing your unmarshalling route, right? So you can send in a raw request, unmarshall it, and test the domain object looks good (and vice versa)

Comment: Can you show an example of your tests and your SOAP request?

Comment: @vikingsteve Unfortunately there are no such tests today.

Comment: @fiw I was successfully using the examples in the "Camel tests" link, but mocking the endpoints didn't unmarshal the message

Comment: I think you need to add unmarshalling via a `.unmarshal(new JaxbDataFormat())` to your route or use a `.convertBodyTo(String.class)` so you can inspect what's being sent to the mock endpoint. The mock endpoint won't unmarshal for you but will allow you to set expectations on it which you can assert have been satisfied.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? How does your code look like? http://camel.apache.org/soap.html